# Approach for building local/city versions of a national website?

Tags: 7

I'm looking for ideas and advices on how to adapt a national website to cities depending on whether the user is logged in or not.

As for a news website, the front page for anon users would be a mashup of nodes from all the regions.
But registered users will set their city during the registration process or later by editing their profile and will then have a local adapted version of the website.

Any ideas on how to achieve this are welcome

Comment: how are you creating locally adapted websites, by using subdomains? ex. www.yoursite.com for the national and city.yoursite.com for each of the cities?

Comment: Well i don't know really. I haven't decided yet. I've considered multiple independent websites (city1.domain.com, city2.domain.com ..) with one shared users database but i've never done anything that deep using drupal so i thought maybe there was a more simple/clever way to do it. Maybe if cities were taxonomy terms but then how would users set a city as their local version ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend the Domain Access module(s) as the easiest way to set this up with multiple sub-sites (even with sub-domains) but still having a central site to control content and access:

> The Domain Access project is a suite of modules that provide tools
>   for running a group of affiliated sites from one Drupal installation
>   and a single shared database. The module allows you to share users,
>   content, and configurations across a group of sites

It comes with a dozen or so helper modules and a few stand-alone projects that make it easy to create and manage sophisticated site networks.

Comment: Very interesting module. It looks very powerful and a bit complex but it seems to fit with i'm trying to do so i'll definitely spend some time looking into it. Thanks!